# Is there an English equivalent of the German word-pair "selbe/gleiche"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In German both words, *selbe* and *gleiche*, mean something like *same* in English. But they have a subtle difference in meaning. Take a look at this sentence:

> We eat the **gleiche** (=same) soup, but we do not eat the **selbe** (=same) soup.

As you can see in the picture below, both people eat the same (*gleiche*) kind of soup, but they don't eat from the same (*selbe*) bowl of soup.

[image: silly picture of two stick figures, one green and one light pink, with his own orange bowl in front of each of them]

Comment: *Same* means both things. You would say *we're eating the same soup*, and *we have the same parents*. You ***could*** use *identical* to mean *gleiche*, and *selfsame* to mean *selbe*, but usually people use *same* for both. There's usually no problem distinguishing the meanings by context.

Comment: And it will sound pretty weird to native English speakers if you say *selfsame* whenever you mean *selbe* and *identical* whenever you mean *gleiche*.

Comment: "gleiche" can be translated by "such as" or "alike", whilst "selbe" is generally (nearly always) translated by "same".

Comment: _Kind of_ could be inserted for the _gleiche_ cases; _We eat the same kind of soup_.

Comment: @Graffito, you'd think that could cause confusion, switching "same kind" to "alike."   In the illustrated situation, I'd use the verbs "have the same" and "share the same" if I were trying to avoid using "same kind."

Answer (score 1):

"same" is used in both situations and if you mean "they are eating from the same bowl" you'd have to say "they are eating from the same bowl".

I believe that distinction, or specificity, cannot be found in Romance Languages either.

Comment: Eating from the same bowl (aus der selben Schüßel) would mean that two people are eating from one bowl. Eating from like bowls (aus einer gleichen Schüßel) means two people eating from two bowls that are similar.